# sending/ receiving email in Java

Tags: java, email, sendmail, post-receive-email

I want to send email through Java (Any email like from yahoo, gmail, or any other part).

I tried the code give [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm), however I get exception as

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1972)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:642)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at myemailtesting.MyEmailTesting.main(MyEmailTesting.java:72)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:432)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:319)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:233)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1938)
    ... 7 more
```

Code I have is

```
/*
* To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/
package myemailtesting;

/**
*
* @author xxxx
*/
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class MyEmailTesting {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("This is EMAIL testing!!!");
        // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
        String to = "xx@gmail.com";

        // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
        String from = "xx@gmail.com";

        // Assuming you are sending email from localhost
        String host = "localhost";

        // Get system properties
        System.out.println("test 001");
        Properties properties = System.getProperties();
        System.out.println("test 002");

        // Setup mail server
        System.out.println("test 003");
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);

        // Get the default Session object.
        System.out.println("test 004");
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

        try {
            // Create a default MimeMessage object.
            System.out.println("test 005");

            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

            System.out.println("test 006");

            // Set From: header field of the header.
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

            System.out.println("test 007");
            // Set To: header field of the header.
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    new InternetAddress(to));

            System.out.println("test 008");
            // Set Subject: header field
            message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");

            System.out.println("test 009");
            // Now set the actual message
            message.setText("This is actual message");

            System.out.println("test 010");
            // Send message
            Transport.send(message);
            System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
        } catch (MessagingException mex) {
            mex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

For de-bugging I was using stateement as `System.out.println("test 00X");`

I got output as

```
This is EMAIL testing!!!
test 001
test 002
test 003
test 004
test 005
test 006
test 007
test 008
test 009
test 010
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25;
```

I tried many codes but I am not getting any output. Getting some exception.

I see at some place, I need to keep SMTP server UP. I don't know what needs to be done. I believe apache commons will be good option.

Could someone help me in below steps

1. jar files that are needed
2. how to setup smptp
3. send email (from any site i.e. from yahoo or gmail or any private email id)

### OR

step by step process for sending email in java...

Comment: you could install a SMTP server in your machine ([Windows XP](http://www.ehow.com/how_4489548_set-up-smtp-server-windows.html) tutorial), configure it and use it, or use an external STMP server like [Gmail](http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this... its working...

```
import org.apache.commons.mail.*;
public class EmailTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Email email = new SimpleEmail();
            email.setSmtpPort(587);
            email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator("emailid@gmail.com",
                    "yourPassword"));
            email.setDebug(true);
            email.setHostName("smtp.gmail.com");
            email.setFrom("emailid@gmail.com");
            email.setSubject("Hi");
            email.setMsg("This is a test mail ... :-)");
            email.addTo("senderId@yahoo.co.in");
            email.setTLS(true);
            email.send();
            System.out.println("Mail sent!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception :: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for a nice snippet of code. Note however that some environments (e.g. Oracle applications) don't like the `Email email = new SimpleEmail();` inside the `try {}` clause. IOW, this statements (and only this statement) should be moved outside the `try {}` clause.

Comment: Actually, what I said was not the whole picture. This `commons.mail` library simply doesn't work in my environment and I have just discovered that [it doesn't work in others' as well](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6849046/1864054). I will be trying `javax.mail` instead.

Comment: Yup. [javax.mail](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6848935/1864054) works like a charm. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is not strictly speaking a Java problem. You need an outgoing SMTP server, one to which you can send the message, and which will take care to deliver it to the proper google, yahoo, aol server.

As "host" you must set that SMTP server, or install an SMTP server on your machine if you like, but is a hard task. Usually big companies and service providers have SMTP servers that accept any mail from inside their networks.

Most SMTP servers however are not open, and will not let you send emails as you like, not for free at least. You can create a gmail account, and use gmail SMTP (smtp.gmail.com), using the account username and password of your Transport to authenticate with Google's SMTP server.

Also, you cannot always specify the "from" header, it could get rewritten by the SMTP server to reflect the actual account the mail was sent from, or could be considered spam at the other end if not arriving from the right SMTP server.

I would suggest you to read about how SMTP works, it's an overcomplicated and rather old protocol, but it's worth knowing how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an SMTP mail server running at localhost:25. Either your mail configuration is wrong and you should be talking to some other mail server, or else you did intend to talk to one in localhost, in which case you need to install and/or run it.